# Creating "updated_at" and "created_at" columns with df.to_sql()

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am currently using pandas and SQLAlchemy to write new tables to a PostgreSQL database. I'm writing these tables using `df.to_sql()`. This works fine and as expected. However, I would like to have 2 columns called "updated_at" and "created_at" which are `datetimes`. How would I go about adding these columns?

I don't see any documentation on adding this without creating actual model classes. Is there a way to avoid doing this since it appears excessive in this case?

Comment: If you are looking at the `DB/SQL`  side of the solution (given your comment to @Gord's answer), you probably should not _tag_ your question with `sqlalchemy` and implement this on the database directly (see: https://x-team.com/blog/automatic-timestamps-with-postgresql/).
_Also I do not believe that `df.to_sql(...)` is able to do the _updates_, hence I think that DB centric solution will be most appropriate._

Answer (score -1):

You can add a column to the DataFrame like so:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")], columns=["id", "txt"])
print(df)
"""
   id  txt
0   1  foo
1   2  bar
"""

df["created_at"] = datetime.now()
print(df)
"""
   id  txt                 created_at
0   1  foo 2022-06-04 16:54:49.680811
1   2  bar 2022-06-04 16:54:49.680811
"""
```

Comment: Will this work in the database if future entries are added or modified?

Comment: No, that's something you would have to implement on the database side. `to_sql()` can't do that for you.